# Is there a way to make the copy to clipboard feature copy the correct row instead of always copying the first row

Tags: javascript, php, html

The copy to clipboard feature with a button works if it is only has exact variable however if it is a echo'd variable which is different on each row then it only copys the first row no matter which button you click. I have tried many different methods and they all seem to do the same. Is there something which I can add in the code which would make the correct row button copy the correct row $dir ?

```js
function copy(element_id) {
  var aux = document.createElement("div");
  aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML;
  aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)");
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.focus();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  <?php echo $dir ?>
</p>
<button onclick="copy('demo')">Copy Keeping Format</button> <br><br>
```

Code:

```
$numresults=$info["count"];
echo"<div style='position: fixed; float: right; padding-left: 450px;'><a class=clear href=javascript:history.go(-1)>Search again</a></div>";
echo "<div><p>There are <b>$numresults</b> results for your search '<i><b>$SearchFor</i></b>'";
if ($numresults>0){

    echo " these are:</p></div>";
    echo "<div>";
    

    for ($x=0; $x<$numresults; $x++) {                          //display the results
        $sam=$info[$x]['samaccountname'][0];
        $disp=$info[$x]['displayname'][0];
        $dir=$info[$x]['homedirectory'][0];
        $fil=$info[$x]['homedirectory'] [0];
        $displayout=substr($sam, 0, 4);
                
        echo "User Name &nbsp;: $sam";
        echo "<br>Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : $disp";
        echo "<br>Home Drive : <a class=clear href=$dir>$dir</a><br>";?>
         <p id="demo<?php echo $i; ?>">
       <?php echo $dir ?>
        </p>
       <button onclick="copy('demo<?php echo $i; ?>')">Copy Keeping Format</button> <br><br>

<script>
function copyTo(input){
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `<p id="demo"><?php echo $dir ?></p>` can repeat many times in the code? If so then obviously you can't identify it using a single `id`, because - by definition - an ID must be _unique_, and that's not the case for you. You'd need to generate a different ID for each `<p>` element

Comment: Hi, That makes sense. What is the best way to do it would you recommend as the tool allows you to search for users by username and the results can be 1 or can be over 100 records and I wanted a button underneath which would copy the $dir.

Comment: Please see the answer below for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `<p id="demo"><?php echo $dir ?></p>` can repeat many times in the code (due to being contained within a loop) then obviously you can't identify it using a single `id`, because - by definition - an ID must be unique, and that's not the case here.

You'd need to generate a different ID for each `<p>` element.

In the simplest case you can just use PHP to add a counter to the ID.

First, outside your loop, initialise a counter:

```
$i = 0;
```

Then, within the loop, use that to make a unique element ID:

```
<p id="demo<?php echo $i; ?>">
  <?php echo $dir ?>
</p>
<button onclick="copy('demo<?php echo $i; ?>')">Copy Keeping Format</button> <br><br>
```

Finally, before your loop ends, increment the counter:

```
$i++;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am having issues getting the loop counter to work. I have added my code into the top of the thread. Can you see how I can add it in? Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have a `for` loop, which always includes a counter, so you can just use `$x` without creating a separate `$i` variable. But, where does your `for` loop end? I don't see the closing `}` in what you've shown? You don't need to put the JS `copyTo` function in the PHP loop - it only needs to be in your page once.

Comment: Hi, Amazing. Its all working now. Thank you for helping! I have a quick question if thats okay. For some reason when the buttons are clicked the page scrolls to the bottom. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious in the code you've shown which would cause that. It sounds like potentially a separate issue, but it's hard to tell. I suggest you open a new stackoverflow question about it and provide a [mre] of the issue there.

Comment: Actually I looked again, I think may be `aux.focus();` is the issue with the focusing thing.